# Prove exist unique solution to the Poisson equation with Neumann's boundary condition iff $\int f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was doing Evans's PDE book in exercise 6.4 needs to prove that:

Assume $U$ is smoothh bounded connected domain in $\Bbb{R}^n$. A function $u \in H^{1}(U)$ is a weak solution of Neumann's problem
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u=f & \text { in } U \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 & \text { on } \partial U
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
if
$$
\int_{U} D u \cdot D v d x=\int_{U} f v d x
$$
for all $v \in H^{1}(U)$. Suppose $f \in L^{2}(U)$. Prove $(*)$ has a weak solution if and only if
$$
\int_{U} f d x=0
$$

We need to use the Lax-Milgram theorem, hence this problem want us to check the coerciveness condition.since the bilinear form $a:H^1\times H^1 \to \Bbb{R}$ is not coercive,I have no idea how to handle it.Maybe we need to consider the bilinear for in a smaller space, that coerciveness condition holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove existence of weak solutions in the space
$$
V=\{u \in H^1(U): \ \int_U u\ dx= 0\},
$$
i.e., apply Lax-Milgram on $V$.

Then verify that such a function is also a solution of the weak formulation for test functions in the larger space $H^1$.

Comment: Oh I see, this needs the Poincare inequality in Evans's book thank you